# Azure SendGrid different domain branding for each key

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I want to have a SendGrid API key with different rights. I want a dev key which can send emails only from a specific domain like DoNotTrustMe.mydomain.com (because it can be lost...) and a prod key which can access mydomain.com. 
How can achive that?
PS: I can't use 2 x SendGrid service on the same tenant...

Comment: Login to the sendgrid portal from azure and create a bunch of keys. Their portal offers this feature

Comment: I know that I can create keys, but how can I restrict access to each key to a specific Authorized Domain? I can't find that...